# How can I wait for a thread to finish running?Thread.join is making my main thread non responsive?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm working on project which sends mails to multiple users using windows application,But what is happening is,when I use Thread.Join() Method it is making my Main UI non-responsive......
What I want is.... I want to run SMTPClienTSetting() method on seperate thread and want my Main UI to remain responsive for other work..I wnat to run this mail sending acvtivity at the background...Please suggest me using threading concept only.....

```
public void SendMail(dataset ds)
        {
                           for(inti=0<ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count<i++)
                            {

                                Thread tMail = new Thread(() => {
                                     resValue = SMTPClienTSetting(ds, mail);

                                });
                                tMail.IsBackground = true;
                                tMail.Start();
                                tMail.Join();
                                if (resValue == "True")
                                {
                                   Thread tPopUp = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.ShowMessagePopUp));
                                   tPopUp.IsBackground = true;
                                  this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate{
                            });
                                   tPopUp.Start();
                                   lblPOpUpInfo = "Message sent successfully to \nAsset Owner : " + AssetOwner + "\n" + "Email : " + RecipientID;

                                }
                                else
                                {
                                     Thread tPopUp = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.ShowMessagePopUp));
                                     tPopUp.IsBackground = true;
                                                                 this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate{
                            });
                                     tPopUp.Start();
                                     lblPOpUpInfo = "Message sending failed to \nAsset Owner :" + AssetOwner + "\n" + "Email : " + RecipientID + "!!!\nPlease check your SMTP details and\nInternet Connection..!!!";
                                }
                         }
        }
        #region Function for setting SMTP Client
                public string SMTPClienTSetting(DataSet ds, MailMessage MailstoSend)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        SmtpClient objsmtp = new SmtpClient();
                        NetworkCredential NetAccess = new NetworkCredential();

                        NetAccess.UserName = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
                        //NetAccess.Password = base64Decode(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString());

                        NetAccess.Password = genFunc.base64Decode(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString());
                        objsmtp.Credentials = NetAccess;

                        objsmtp.Host = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][2].ToString();
                        objsmtp.Port = Convert.ToInt16(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][3].ToString());

                        objsmtp.Send(MailstoSend);

                        //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

                        return "True";
                    }
                    catch (NullReferenceException nr)
                    {
                        return nr.Message;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        return ex.Message;
                    }
                }
                #endregion
        }

    #region Function to show Pop Up window using separate thread
    public void ShowMessagePopUp()
    {
           try
            {
                frmHomePopUp homePopUp = new frmHomePopUp();
                mailTimer.Elapsed += delegate { mailTimer.Stop(); homePopUp.Close(); };
                //mailTimer.Elapsed += this.TimeEvent;
                mailTimer.Interval=5000;
                mailTimer.Enabled = true;
                homePopUp.lblInfo.Text = lblPOpUpInfo;
                homePopUp.Refresh();
                mailTimer.Start();
                homePopUp.ShowDialog();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

    }
    #endregion

    public  void mailTimer_Elapsed(object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        //frmHome home;
        mailTimer.Stop();
      }
```

Comment: Which version of C# are you using?

Comment: Wait == not doing anything == being unresponsive.  Don't wait.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically: don't use `Thread.Join`; what that *does* is block.

An appropriate approach would be to do any UI work *at the end of the worker method*:

```
Thread tMail = new Thread(() => {
     resValue = SMTPClienTSetting(ds, mail);

     if (resValue == "True") {
        // blah blah blah
     }
     // now: if you need to update any UI state:
     this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
        someControl.Text = lblPOpUpInfo; // for example
     });
});
tMail.IsBackground = true;
tMail.Start();
```

The call to `Invoke` / `BeginInvoke` switches back to the UI thread, essentially working as a callback.

Note that you might also want to use `ThreadPool` rather than a `Thread` here.

Comment: Hi Mark,this.BeginInvoke solved my problem.But i want to do slight modification.Please suggest me how to do it. if(resValue==True),i need to perform some more action,please suggest me how to do it.Please see the code i have edited it.....

Comment: Hi Mark, When I get resValue,I want to show lblPopUpInfo.Text in new window for 5 secs and want to close it and again I want to open it for next message.I want to do it like PopUp window in ASP.NET.So this opening and closing problem is happening...

Comment: @VishalIPatil same problem really; you don't "wait" by `Thread.Sleep(5000)`. You **need** to let the UI thread finish quickly. Instead, create a `Timer` with a duration of 5 seconds, and when the timer fires: close the form.

Comment: Hi Mark, According to your guidance I used a timer to wait for 5 seconds,and after 5 seonds i need to close my form...How to do it???I have used thread.abort()...This is generating mssage called thread is being aborted.... I want to close my form in mailTimer_Elapsed() method,please help me..See the code I have edited it.... Please add your code,if possible...

Comment: @VishalIPatil `homePopUp.Close();` ?

Comment: Object homePopUp is not accessible outisde ShowMessagePopUp()
How to access it....If I declare it in the class level...It is accessible, but homePopUp.Close() telling cross threading operation is not allowed??

Comment: @VishalIPatil then you need to *make* it accessible ;p It was probably a mistake to start the form (via `ShowMessagePopUp`) on a background thread; `ShowMessagePopUp` should probably do a `BeginInvoke` to get back to the UI thread. Overall, though, it sounds like you're over-complicating things.

Comment: Just tell me how to passs the object homePopup from ShowMessagePopUp() to mailTimer_Elapsed(object source, EventArgs e) method??

Comment: @VishalIPatil how about `mailTimer.Elapsed+=delegate{ mailTimer.Stop(); homePopUp.Close(); }` and move `mailTimer` completely into the same scope as `homePopUp` ?

Comment: Hey I used delgate method suggested by you to close homePopUp.Close but it is telling {"Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'frmHomePopUp' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."}....

Comment: @VishalIPatil and did you do anything to change the fact that you're creating that form on a background thread?

Comment: No,I didn't change anything,Background property for the thread is true...I have updated the changed portion in the above code....

Comment: @VishalIPatil I already mentioned how to do that (50 minutes ago); please go do that.

Comment: I added this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate{}); just befor the thread.start() of ShowMessagePopUp(); But still it is showing Cross thread Operaion Error...I have updated the code...Just see whether I'm doing correct thing????...Hey I'm little new to these threading concepts,don't get irritated if I ask too many silly questions....

Comment: @VishalIPatil move all of the existing code **inside** the `delegate { /* here */ }`: the point being that it needs to be back on the UI thread **when** it creates the other form

Comment: Hi Mark,using this solved my problem.... mailTimer.Elapsed += delegate { mailTimer.Stop(); homePopUp.Invoke(new ClosePopupDelegate(homePopUp.Close)); }; Thank you very much for ur answers....