# C# wait for MethodInvoker to finish

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, invoke

I need to accomplish the following scenario. ThreadMethod() is a Timer method, where I have UI update in the Invoke statement. I need to wait till the Invoke finish its work, and then continue the method. How can I cope with this?

```
public void ThreadMethod(){
//do some work

            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
            //do some GUI update
            });

//wait till Invoke finish its work    
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14137938/961113

Comment: It already works that way, only BeginInvoke() doesn't wait.

Comment: You are already waiting. Invoke is blocking and returns once the delegate is executed.

Comment: Its not waiting, I made a test example:  `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            Console.Write("1");
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
                Console.Write("2");
            });`                                                      and the output is 112112

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't need to do anything.  `Invoke` (unlike `BeginInvoke`) will block until the scheduled delegate has finished executing.

Comment: So why does this code:   `public void ThreadMethod()  {  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);  Console.Write("1");  this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate  {  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);  Console.Write("2");});  } ` output:112112, I expected:121212

Comment: @user1816806 The code you just provided would print `12`, not either of the things you just mentioned.

Comment: I mentioned that its a Time method on every 1 second.

Comment: @user1816806 No, you didn't actually.  Of course, that makes the output you're seeing entirely sensible, as you're invoking this operation multiple times concurrently (as it's taking longer to run than the interval) meaning the output can be just about anything.  If you just run it once, you'll see `12`, demonstrating that `Invoke` is blocking.

Comment: Ah ok, didn't expect that its going concurrently, So I must change the timer to a Task and make Sleep(1000) at the end. Thanks alot.